# SQL Like Conditions won't display my search data C# and Ms Access

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I tried doing a query via MS Access (SELECT mname, mcellno WHERE mcellno LIKE '0922*') it result to display my desire data.
While this one

```
    private Int32 getMemberNo()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = db.konek();
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS x FROM members";
        Int32 count = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                count = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["x"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public String[,] displayMobilePrefix() //THIS FUNCTION
    {
        con.ConnectionString = db.konek();
        String sql = "SELECT mname, mcellno FROM members WHERE mcellno LIKE '" + @mcellno + "*'";
        int count = this.getMemberNo();
        String[,] ars = new String[2, count];
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@mcellno", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = this.mcellno;
            OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int counter = 0;
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                ars[0, counter] = rdr["mname"].ToString();
                ars[1, counter] = rdr["mcellno"].ToString();
                counter++;
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return ars; //never returns any data
    }
```

it wont return any data. However I tried to add a parameter on my String Query and it returns nothing.

Comment: what is the datatype of `mcellno`?

Comment: What happens if you run the the sql query from the database?  Does it get something then?  (You'd put in a reasonable value for @mcellno.)

Answer (score 3):

With OleDb, your Access query must use `%` instead of `*` as the wild card character.

```
String sql = "SELECT mname, mcellno FROM members WHERE mcellno LIKE '" + @mcellno + "%'";
```